# facing problems using checkbox form-controls in cakephp project using materialize css framework

Tags: cakephp-3.0, materialize

My cakephp template file is

```
<div class="row">
<div class="members form col l6 m8 s12 offset-l3 offset-m2 ">
<h3>Introduce a Member</h3>
<div class="divider"></div>
<br>
    <?= $this->Form->create($member) ?>
        <div class='input-field'>
            <?= $this->Form->input('name',array('div'=>'input')); ?>
        </div>
        <div class='input-field'>
            <?= $this->Form->input('father_or_husband'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class='input-field'>
            <?= $this->Form->input('age'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class='input-field'>
            <?= $this->Form->input('post'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class='input-field'>
            <?= $this->Form->input('school_name'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class='input-field'>
            <?= $this->Form->input('current_status'); ?>
        </div><br>
        <div class="row">
            <?= $this->Form->input('date_of_retirement',array(
                                                        'type'=>'date',
                                                            'class'=>'datepicker'
                                                            )); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field row">
            <?= 
                $this->Form->input('payment_status',array('type'=>'checkbox'));
             ?>
        </div><br>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'),['class'=>'waves-effect waves-light btn']); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Although I am trying to use the checkbox and datepicker here. But they did not appear in my project when browsed. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

@Aditya Soni, Materialize checkboxes are wrapped in `<label>` tags. I had the same problem.
In order to solve this problem, I had to use jquery to wrap my checkboxes in `<label>` tags withing my code like below:

`<script>`
$('#PaymentStatus').wrap(`"<label></label>"`);
`</script>`

Answer (score 0):

To generate checkbox you need to do something like this, rather than defining type:

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('payment_status');
```

Your form helper for date looks fine. If you are trying to use bootstrap datepicker or any other plugin simply use input as a type:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('date_of_retirement',array('class'=>'datepicker')); ?>
```

See Here ([CakePHP form helper](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)).

Comment: I modified my code according to your suggestion but the checkbox doesn't even shows up. I am using materialize CSS framework with my cakephp project I am facing problems in using checkbox in materialize framework. Can you suggest me some other  solution.